# Open GL ES 2.0: How to query a value in a shader?

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, shader, getter-setter

I can set a value in my shader like so:

```
public void setOpacity(float op){

    GLES20.glUseProgram(iProgId);

    // get handle to transformation matrix
    mOpacityHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(iProgId, "opValue");

    //Apply the opacity value
    GLES20.glUniform1f(mOpacityHandle, op);

}
```

This works fine (in this particular instance, I am using this code to set the opacity of my quad)

However, how would I be able to query the value that I just set from the shader?  For example to use in a `getOpacity` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenGL ES has no provision for reading values back from any shader.  This is why shader code can be really difficult to debug.

It is possible to read back what the fragment shader renders into the framebuffer with glReadPixels(), but this is so slow that it's really only practical as a debugging technique.

Answer (score 1):

You can't read back values written *by* the shader, but you can read back the value of a *uniform* from the program state using glGetUniformfv.

So the getter corresponding to your setter would be something like:

```
public float getOpacity(void){
    float value;

    mOpacityHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(iProgId, "opValue");

    GLES20.glGetUniformfv(iProgId, mOpacityHandle, &value);
    return value;
}
```

See the [Khronos man pages](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetUniform.xml) for further info.

Comment: This is a good point, but I think glGetUniform only allows you to read back from the shader the same values that were input to the shader, so it's not particularly useful.